# SQL - "NOT IN" in WHERE clause using INNER JOIN not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I need to filter a table based in a sub table data.

I'll exemplify with a hypnotic data to be easier to explain:

- Master table: `Cars`
- Sub table: `Attributes` (like `Color`, `car type`, `accessories`)

These attributes have an id (`idOption`) and the selected value (`idList`)

So, in an example, I need to filter all the cars with the color (`idOption = 10`) yellow (`idList = 45`). I can't filter this directly because the search need to consider the other option's results (which include the types, accessories.

When I use `NOT IN` for just one table, it works. But when I use merging the 2 tables with `INNER JOIN`, it does not work.

So in summary, I need to filter the 3 idOption (when is not NULL) with a given value, and this needs to reflect in the main table, grouped by product.

Table **Cars**:

```
idProduct  |  Description
1             Product A
2             Product B
3             Product C
```

Table **Attributes**:

```
idRow   idProduct   idOption    idList
---------------------------------------
1       1           10          45
2       2           10          46
3       3           10          47
4       1           11          10
5       2           11          98
6       1           14          56
7       3           16          28
8       2           20          55
```

This is the stored procedure that I created which is not working:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_TestSearch]
    (@Param1 BIGINT = NULL,
     @PValue1 BIGINT = NULL,
     @Param2 BIGINT = NULL,
     @PValue2 BIGINT = NULL,
     @Param3 BIGINT = NULL,
     @PValue3 BIGINT = NULL)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        Cars.idProduct,
        Cars.[Description]
    FROM 
        Cars
    INNER JOIN 
        Attributes ON Cars.idProduct = Attributes.idProduct
    WHERE
        ((@Param1 IS NULL OR (idOption NOT IN (@Param1)))
        AND
        (@Param2 IS NULL OR (idOption NOT IN (@Param2)))
        AND
        (@Param3 IS NULL OR (idOption NOT IN (@Param3))))
        OR
        (idOption = ISNULL(@Param1, NULL) 
         AND idList = ISNULL(@PValue1, NULL))
        OR
        (idOption = ISNULL(@Param2, NULL) 
         AND idList = ISNULL(@PValue2, NULL))
        OR
        (idOption = ISNULL(@Param3, NULL) 
         AND idList = ISNULL(@PValue3, NULL))
    GROUP BY 
        Cars.idProduct, Cars.[Description]
```

Comment: TestProducts.idProduct, TestProducts.[Description] ## there is no TestProducts table.  What is meant here?  Cars or Attributes?  Also, when executed, what parm/&/value gives good results, and what parms/&/values fail?

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the name to post here and forgot to change in the SELECT part. You can consider the table Cars as TestProducts. The parameters can be NULL or for Param1, Param2 and Param3 -> Valid values listed in the idOption column and PValue1,PValue2 and PValue3 -> Valid values listed in the idList column

Comment: what is your expected results from the given sample ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would edit the question and change TestProducts to Cars instead of just stating that in the comment.

Comment: I suspect that you're looking for something like `select * from Cars.TestProducts where not exists ( select 42 from Attributes as A where A.idOption = 10 and A.idList = 45 and A.idProduct = Cars.TestProducts.idProduct )`.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Why you're using in here in the first place?

Comment: You are converting a value to NULL when it is NULL by - ISNULL(@Param2, NULL). Is that really make sense? Can you add you add your expected output from 2 tables?

Comment: Erland discusses in great detail the use of optional parameters in [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) page of his website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code demonstrates how to implement the logic of excluding vehicles from query results if they have *any* "bad" property values. The rejection is handled by `... where not exists ...` which is used to check each car against the "bad" property values.

Rather than using an assortment of (hopefully) paired parameters to pass the undesirable properties, the values are passed in a table. The stored procedure to implement this ought to use a [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) (TVP) to pass the table.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Cars as Table ( CarId Int Identity, Description VarChar(16) );
insert into @Cars ( Description ) values
  ( 'Esplanade' ), ( 'Tankigator' ), ( 'Land Yacht' );
select * from @Cars;

declare @Properties as Table ( PropertyId Int Identity, Description VarChar(16) );
insert into @Properties ( Description ) values
  ( 'Turbochargers' ), ( 'Superchargers' ), ( 'Hyperchargers' ), ( 'Color' ), ( 'Spare Tires' );
select * from @Properties;

declare @CarProperties as Table ( CarId Int, PropertyId Int, PropertyValue Int );
insert into @CarProperties ( CarId, PropertyId, PropertyValue ) values
  ( 1, 1, 1 ), ( 1, 4, 24 ), ( 1, 4, 42 ), -- Two tone!
  ( 2, 2, 1 ), ( 2, 4, 7 ),
  ( 3, 1, 2 ), ( 3, 4, 0 ), ( 3, 5, 6 );
select C.CarId, C.Description as CarDescription,
  P.PropertyId, P.Description as PropertyDescription,
  CP.PropertyValue
  from @Cars as C inner join
    @CarProperties as CP on CP.CarId = C.CarId inner join
    @Properties as P on P.PropertyId = CP.PropertyId
  order by C.CarId, P.PropertyId;

-- Test data: Avoid vehicles that have _any_ of these property values.
--   This should be passed to the stored procedure as a table-value parameter (TVP).
declare @BadProperties as Table ( PropertyId Int, PropertyValue Int );
insert into @BadProperties ( PropertyId, PropertyValue ) values
  ( 2, 1 ), ( 2, 2 ), ( 2, 4 ),
  ( 4, 62 ), ( 4, 666 );
select BP.PropertyId, BP.PropertyValue, P.Description
  from @BadProperties as BP inner join
    @Properties as P on P.PropertyId = BP.PropertyId;

-- Query the data.
select C.CarId, C.Description as CarDescription
  from @Cars as C
  where not exists ( 
    select 42
      from @CarProperties as CP inner join
        @BadProperties as BP on BP.PropertyId = CP.PropertyId and BP.PropertyValue = CP.PropertyValue
      where CP.CarId = C.CarId )
  order by C.CarId;
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things here.

Firstly, this kind of catch all procedure is a bit of an anti pattern for all sorts of reasons, see here for a full explanation:- https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/

Secondly, you need to be very careful of using NOT IN with nullable values in a list: http://www.sqlbadpractices.com/using-not-in-operator-with-null-values/

I've added the DDL for the tables:-

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('Attributes') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Attributes;

IF OBJECT_ID('Cars') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Cars;

IF OBJECT_ID('SP_GET_TestSearch') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE SP_GET_TestSearch

CREATE TABLE Cars
(idProduct INT PRIMARY KEY
, Description VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Attributes
(idRow INT PRIMARY KEY
, idProduct INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Cars(idProduct)
, idOption INT NOT NULL
, idList INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO dbo.Cars
VALUES
(1, 'Product A')
,(2 , 'Product B')
,(3, 'Product C');

INSERT INTO dbo.Attributes
(
    idRow,
    idProduct,
    idOption,
    idList
)
VALUES (1,1,10,45)
,(2,2,10,46)
,(3,3,10,47)
,(4,1,11,10)
,(5,2,11,98)
,(6,1,14,56)
,(7,3,16,28)
,(8,2,20,55);
GO
```

The issue with your query, is that the first part of the block is always evaluated to TRUE for any idOption that you *don't* specify:-

```
((@Param1 IS NULL OR (idOption NOT IN (@Param1)))
AND
(@Param2 IS NULL OR (idOption NOT IN (@Param2)))
AND
(@Param3 IS NULL OR (idOption NOT IN (@Param3))))
```

To explain; if I pass in the following:-

```sql
DECLARE @Param1 BIGINT
, @Param2 BIGINT
, @Param3 BIGINT
, @PValue1 BIGINT
, @PValue2 BIGINT
, @PValue3 BIGINT;

SET @Param1 = 11
SET @Pvalue1 = 42
SET @Param2 = 11
SET @Pvalue2 = 10
SET @Param3 = 14
SET @PValue3= 56

EXEC dbo.SP_GET_TestSearch @Param1, @PValue1, @Param2, @PValue2, @Param3, @PValue3
```

Then you effectively have `WHERE idOption NOT IN (11,14)` as the evaluation for the first part of the clause, so all other rows are returned.

I suspect you really want the WHERE clause to be:-

```sql
WHERE 
       (@Param1 IS NULL AND @Param2 IS NULL AND @Param3 IS NULL)
       OR
       (idOption = @Param1 
         AND idList = @PValue1)
        OR
        (idOption = @Param2 
         AND idList = @PValue2)
        OR
        (idOption = @Param3 
         AND idList = @PValue3)
```